# Java multiple inputs lead to an exception

Tags: java, lambda, project, palindrome, composite

When I input in in a "1 2" format it gives error if in "1 enter 2" It gives error

I'm tasked to create a lambda that has a function that deals with knowing what the user input is.
The user would chose to determine either odd, even, prime, composite or palindrome. But I cant use this as a reference as it doesn't give any instruction on how to use it.

The first one gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 1"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at Lambda_Project/Project.Solution.main(Solution.java:45)
```

The second one is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:348)
    at Lambda_Project/Project.Solution.main(Solution.java:53)
```

Here's the Code ...

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    interface PerformOperation {
        boolean check(int a);
    }
    class MyMath {
        public boolean checker(PerformOperation p, int num) {
            return p.check(num);
        }
    
        public PerformOperation is_odd() {
            return n -> (n & 1) == 1;
        }
    
        public PerformOperation is_prime() {
            // O(n^(1/2)) runtime
            return n -> {
                if (n < 2) {
                    return false;
                }
                int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
                for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++) {
                    if (n % i == 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            };
        }
    
        public PerformOperation is_palindrome() {
            return n -> {
                String original = Integer.toString(n);
                String reversed = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(n)).reverse().toString();
                return original.equals(reversed);
            };
        }
    }
    
    public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            MyMath ob = new MyMath();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  // IT ERRORS HERE
            PerformOperation op;
            boolean ret = false;
            String ans = null;
            while (T--> 0) {
                String s = br.readLine().trim();
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
                int ch = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                int num = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // AND HERE
                if (ch == 1) {
                    op = ob.is_odd();
                    ret = ob.checker(op, num);
                    ans = (ret) ? "ODD" : "EVEN";
                } else if (ch == 2) {
                    op = ob.is_prime();
                    ret = ob.checker(op, num);
                    ans = (ret) ? "PRIME" : "COMPOSITE";
                } else if (ch == 3) {
                    op = ob.is_palindrome();
                    ret = ob.checker(op, num);
                    ans = (ret) ? "PALINDROME" : "NOT PALINDROME";
                }
                System.out.println(ans);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"1 2"` is not a string representing an `int` and therefore, it can not be parsed into an `int`.

You need to split the such an input and then you can parse the individual elements into `int` values and perform the required arithmetic operation on them e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "1 2";
        String[] arr = input.split("\\s+");// Split on whitespace
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s + " + 10 = " + (Integer.parseInt(s) + 10));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 + 10 = 11
2 + 10 = 12
```